# How to test for falsity in implications?

Tags: isabelle

In a complex lemma which is basically an implication one may mistakenly form an antecedent that turns out to be falsity. Is there any support in Isabelle for avoiding this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `quickcheck` for that. In a proof where you suspect your antecedents don't hold, locally try to prove `False`:

```
lemma "P ∧ ¬ P ⟹ foobar"
proof -
  have False
    quickcheck
```

In case it's an antecedent that you need frequently, you can also do it like this:

```
context
  assumes "P ∧ ¬ P"
begin

lemma False
  nitpick
  quickcheck

end
```

The `context` command opens a new unnamed context with local hypotheses. When you exit the context, the assumption gets added to all theorems. There, you can also use `nitpick` to find problems.

Comment: Another common thing to try is to simply provide a model for your assumptions, i.e. try to actually apply your theorem to something concrete. Even a trivial example will at least show that your assumptions are not inconsistent, and a non-trivial example will also increase your confidence that you actually did formalise what you intended correctly.

Comment: By the way, this happens all the time. Even to experienced users of proof assistants. Great care is needed to avoid this kind of situation.

Comment: larsrh, thank you for your answer. The second version works fine but with the first version I get "Nitpicking goal: False Nitpick found a counterexample: Empty assignment", no matter the antecedent is falsity or not. Could you explain a bit more how to use  it?

Comment: @AttilaKaroly Thanks, I've updated the answer accordingly.